# How to provide a XPS file path as a local port?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printers

Below here is a code snippet what I m trying out:

```
PRINTER_INFO_2 pi;
BOOL Result = FALSE;
HANDLE pHd; 

memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(PRINTER_INFO_2));
pi.pPrinterName = L"RxXPSDrv";  
pi.pDriverName = L"XPSDrv Sample Driver";
// Select Share Name
pi.pShareName = L"MyPrinter";
// Select Server Name
pi.pServerName = NULL;

// Select Port Name
pi.pPortName = L"COM3:";
//pi.pPortName = L"C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\a1.xps";

pi.pSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
// Select Print Processor
pi.pPrintProcessor = L"winprint";
// Select Attributes
pi.Attributes = PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_DO_COMPLETE_FIRST | PRINTER_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL;
// Set Priority
pi.Priority = 1;
// Call the function AddPrinter
pHd = AddPrinter(NULL, 2, (LPBYTE)&pi);
```

Here @**pi.pPortName** I need to provide **C:\Users\admin\Desktop\a1.xps** but its not working and the printer isn't getting added. With **COM3** it works fine.
Can anyone tell me how can I do this? How can I provide full path of a **XPS** to **pi.pPortName**?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a "local port" "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\a1.xps" first. I just tried and it worked. Some code for Add port: [Adding-a-Local-Port-through-XcvData-and-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/92982/Adding-a-Local-Port-through-XcvData-and-C)

Comment: I have to use C++ only, I ain't supposed to use any framework. So can u tell me how can add local printer port using C++ winapi?